# Documentation comment for multi-return-value functions in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, comments

Swift3 supports functions with multiple return values, for example

```
func foo(param1: Int, param2: Double) -> (retA: String, retB: [Int]) {
    // ...
}
```

when creating documentation comment for this function, we can use

```
/// function `foo` .....
/// 
/// - Parameters:
///   - param1: xxx
///   - param2: xxx
```

to create statements of `param1` and `param2`. Then, how to create statements for `retA` and `retB`? If I use

```
/// - Returns:
///   - retA: xxx
///   - retB: xxx
```

the quick help just treat `retA` and `retB` as two Markdown items, and cannot get the same effect with `param1` and `param2`.

Comment: Anything new on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to get what you're trying to do.

This is because although you can use multiple return types, it's internally transformed into a tuple (which is a single value). Taking this into account and the fact that the [quickhelp documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SymbolDocumentation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH51-SW1) says:

> The Parameters section lists the parameters for a method or function.
>
> The Returns section documents any return value for a method or function.

Notice how the parameters is shown as a plural while the return is a single value (in this case a tuple).

You might have better luck simply formatting the return using markdown to give it a nicer format.